# starting IPython using Python code

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I'm in a Python 2.7 shell on Windows and, because I'm going crazy without tab completion and `?` documentation, I want to start an IPython shell from there.

For various (really tedious) reasons I can't launch IPython directly via `Scripts\ipython.exe`. I just want pure-Python code that will take me to IPython.  I've searched-for and found the following:

```
from IPython.terminal.ipapp import TerminalIPythonApp as t;
t.instance().initialize()
```

or

```
from IPython.terminal.ipapp import TerminalInteractiveShell as t;
t.instance()
```

...and in both of these cases I end up in some kind of IPython shell, but in both it's not what I recognize as a "normal" IPython session: for example it lacks colour, lacks the `[1]` next to `In` and `Out`,  and lacks the ability to use `?` and `??` to view docstrings.

Is there a way to get to the "normal"-looking and -behaving IPython shell from Python, without having to come out of Python and launch directly from the `.exe`?  In principle I imagine there must be a pure-Python (and hence cross-platform, not even Windows-specific) way of doing it, but I'm googling in circles trying to find it.

Comment: The "tedious reasons" are related to the fact that, because of third-party-package dependency hell, I have multiple Python distributions: some have `IPython<=0.13`, some are more modern.  Two are Python 2.7.x, but one is 3.2 and one is even 2.5.4 (ugh). One even lacks `setuptools` and (for even more tedious reasons) I want to keep it that way.  On my PsychoPy distro (Python 2.7.3, with setuptools) `ipython.exe` just fails silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from ipython starter script in linux.

```
from IPython import start_ipython
start_ipython()
```

Comment: Looks like this is indeed the best and most "IPythonic" answer provided one's version of the package is modern enough. That's not always the case for me, but I didn't tell you that in the question, and your answer put me on the right track to cover my other bases---thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By following the lead of `Scripts\ipython-script.py` and looking at what `pkg_resources.load_entry_point` returns in various cases, I ended up with the following script, which seems to cover all my bases:

```
import sys
import IPython
try:
    from IPython import start_ipython as entry_point
except ImportError:
    try:
        from IPython.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance as entry_point
    except ImportError:
        try:
            from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance as entry_point
        except ImportError:
            try:
                from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
                entry_point = load_entry_point( 'ipython', 'console_scripts', 'ipython' )
            except ImportError:
                try:
                    from pkg_resources import run_script
                    def entry_point(): run_script( 'ipython', 'ipython' ); return 0
                except ImportError:
                    raise ImportError( 'run out of options for launching IPython version %s under Python version %s' % ( IPython.__version__, sys.version ) )
sys.exit( entry_point() )
```